# How to bind to event in parent viewmodel from child viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I am currently following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView) guide for setting up a TreeView with checkboxes. In my code, the tree "FooViewModel" is initiated in my MainViewModel and bound to the TreeView as an ItemsSource. I want to be able to subscribe to some event in the MainViewModel that will trigger when something is checked or unchecked. That way I can iterate through the "FooViewModel" and check which nodes have IsChecked = True. How do I create this event binding?

This is the code I have:

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsInitiallySelected, Mode=OneTime}" />
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="xn:VirtualToggleButton.IsVirtualToggleButton" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="xn:VirtualToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
</Style>

<xn:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionFooViewModel}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">
    <xn:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="2,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </xn:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</xn:TreeView>
```

I figured if there's a way to bind "IsChecked" to two properties (one in FooViewModel, another in MainViewModel) I would have my answer.

Comment: If you would add your code for the style and template you used, or avoid using them in the code you give by creating this scenario in a simpler less "designed" code it could help us understand what it is you are trying to accomplish and come up with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to achieve this. One would be some kind of a pub/sub (messaging) implementation or maybe just bunch of `Action` delegates? Something like...

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="300"
        Width="250">

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionFooViewModel}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Focusable="False" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}"
                                      Margin="2,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

**DataContext**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Action<MyItem> action = item => Console.WriteLine(@"MyItem was clicked");

        CollectionFooViewModel = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>()
        {
            new MyItem()
            {
                Name = "MyItem1",
                Children = new List<MyItem>()
                { 
                    new MyItem()
                    {
                        Name = "MySubItem1", 
                        IsChecked = false, 
                        Action = item => Console.WriteLine(@"{0} invoked action", item.Name)
                    },
                    new MyItem()
                    {
                        Name = "MySubItem2", 
                        IsChecked = true, 
                        Action = item => Console.WriteLine(@"{0} state is {1} ", item.Name, item.IsChecked)
                    },
                },
                Action = action
            }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> CollectionFooViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;

            if (Action != null)
                Action.BeginInvoke(this, null, null);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyItem> Children { get; set; }
    public Action<MyItem> Action { get; set; }
}
```

Which gives you the following...

[image: imgur]

...and spits this out to console when clicked in order.

> MyItem was clicked
>   MySubItem1 invoked action
>   MySubItem2 state is False

Of course, in your case, you might want to pass concrete method to delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "OnPropertyEventChanged" method call in the setter for your model, here is an example of what I mean:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have that but since I can only subscribe to the propertychange event for the top node and not the child nodes when they are checked, it doesn't solve my issue.